# Boolean is printed as 'value' in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Here is the html in view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="HasDetails" id="HasDetials" value="@Model.HasDetails" />
```

`Model.HasDetails` is boolean?, and this is the result in broswer

```
<input type="hidden" name="HasDetails" id="HasDetials" value="value">
```

What I expect is

```
<input type="hidden" name="HasDetails" id="HasDetials" value="true">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="HasDetails" id="HasDetials" value="false">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the HTML helper:

```
@HTML.CheckBoxFor (m => m.HasDetails)
```

If you want to write your own HTML, then use the helper as a one-off to generate the correct HTML then copy that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using something like:

```
var MyBool = Convert.ToBoolean(Model.HasDetails);
```

So, then you can use "MyBool" as value.

```
<input value="@MyBool">
```